# Sending a post Jsoup request to Server using Android

Tags: android, web-services, http, http-post, jsoup

I have never send and receive data using Jsoup before, i am a bit stuck right now. 
**Background:**

I have included jsoup library as well in my code. It gives me following warning and does not process further

```
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607): org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL=http://107.170.91.100/books/save_feedback
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:449)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.post(HttpConnection.java:173)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at com.example.lms.Form$Networ.doInBackground(Form.java:170)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at com.example.lms.Form$Networ.doInBackground(Form.java:1)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
04-15 00:09:54.044: W/System.err(15607):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
```

**Here is my code:**

@Override
          protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

```
            try {
                Document document = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://107.170.91.100/books/save_feedback")
                        .data("q1", q1).data("q2", q2).data("q3", q3).data("q4", q4).data("q5", q5).data("q6", q6).data("q7", q7).data("q8", q8)
                        .data("q9", q9).data("q10", q10)
                        .data("latitude", "234").data("longitude", "344.4").data("imei", ime)
                        .data("time", MainActivity.b64)
                        .post();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

PS: I would like to know one more thing, how can i send integer or float data on server as well, right now i am try to send data of type string only.

Answer (score 1):

You receive a [bad request](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html) response from the server. You can see that on the returned error number 400. This means that the URL that you try to access is not accessible in the way you try.

My guess is, that you need to first login to this service and then send along all the session cookies.